# oracle apex strange zero division problem

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have simple report (not interactive). When I try to remove column from its backing sql query it throws an exception

> ORA-01476: divisor is equal to zero

**UPD**: exception is thrown after I try to remove a.page_name and save report

```
select a.page_name,a.page_id, b.report_name
from APEX_WORKSPACE_ACTIVITY_LOG a, reports b, APEX_APPLICATION_PAGE_IR c
where 
c.interactive_report_id = b.interactive_report_id
and c.page_id = a.page_id
and a.apex_user = :APP_USER --NVL(v('APP_USER'), USER)
and a.application_id = '157'
```

Comment: More info needed - does this error occur when you run the page, or when you try to save the change to the SQL?  Could you post the SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the column you are removing is being used somewhere.
Try exporting the application and grepping the file for page_name

Answer (score 0):

On the face of it that sounds like a bug in your version of Apex.  If possible, recreate the problem in a public page on [apex.oracle.com](http://apex.oracle.com) and then raise the issue on the [Oracle Apex forum](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=137) with a link to the example.  The Apex development team participate in the forum and may be able to help.